# Statement that compress files older than X and after it removes old ones

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to do a `bash` script, that will compress files older than X, and after compressing removes uncompressed version. Tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -exec gzip {}\ | -exec rm;
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of commands before asking questions here. Try `man find` and `man gzip` on your computer.

Comment: The `|` is wrong in your command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, [`gzip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) will remove the uncompressed file (since it replaces it with the compressed variant). And you don't want it to run on anything else than a plain file (not on directories or devices, not on symbolic links).

So you want at least

```
 find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -type f -exec gzip {} \;
```

You could even want [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to avoid files with *several* hard links. And you might also want it to ask you before running the command. Then you could try:

```
find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -type f -links 1 -ok gzip {} \;
```

The `find` command with `-exec` or `-ok`  wants a semicolon (or a `+` sign), and you need to [escape](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html) that semicolon `;`  from your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell). You could use `';'` instead of `\;` to [quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) it...

If you use a `+` the `find` command will group several arguments (to a single `gzip` process), so will run less processes (but they would last longer). So you could try

```
 find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -type f -links 1 -exec gzip -v {} +
```

You may want to read more about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and how a shell [works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398464/50557).

BTW, you don't need any [command pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) (as suggested by the wrong use of `|` in your question).

You could even consider using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run things in parallel, or feed some shell (with background jobs) with e.g.

```
find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -type f -links 1 \
  -exec printf "gzip %s &\n" {} \; | bash -x
```

but in practice you won't speed up a lot your processing.

Comment: I've checked it, and files gets compressed, but uncompressed version still exists.. maybe i should add something like  `| -exec rm;`  ?

Comment: Are you really sure, I don't observe this behavior when trying the commands I am suggesting. Did you escape the semicolon as needed?

Comment: And you should remove the `|` from your command. It is wrong. Notice that I don't use any `|` in my suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -exec gzip {} +
```

This bash script compresses the files you find with the "find command". Instead of generating new files in gzip format, convert the files to gzip format. Let's say you have three files named older than X. And their names are a, b, c.

After running `find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -exec gzip {} +` command, you will see a.gz, b.gz, c.gz instead of seeing a, b, c in /home/randomcat directory.

Comment: I'm not sure of that. `find` wants a semi-colon, and it should be escaped to avoid being handled by the shell.

Comment: You were right, it was a mistake. "find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -exec gzip {}\;" or ""find /home/randomcat -mtime +11 -exec gzip {} +" must be used

Comment: Then you need to edit your answer (or delete it). I don't understand the first line and the backslash in it.

Comment: Why the double quote in the first line?

Comment: What's the difference between `+` and `\;` at the end of the `find` command?

Comment: Good answer about the difference between `find ... +` and `find ... \;` : https://askubuntu.com/a/558819/329317

Answer (score 0):

```
find /location/location -type f -ctime +15 -exec mv {} /location/backup_location \;
```

**This will help you find all the files and move to backup folder**